# Why would a QGroupBox automatically hook up to a QStackedWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I have been messing with pyqt5 to make a functional UI. My goal for this question is to understand how and why a QGroupBox automatically hooks up to a QStackedWidget with QRadioButtons when there is no explicit code to hook them up.

Basically, I expect "round_changed" to get called, but it does not. I have verified this with the debugger built into pycharm. Yet when a QRadioButton is clicked, the QStackWidget changes the displayed widget. What I don't understand is why "round_3" becomes the top widget of "round_widget" when "radio_button_round_3" is clicked and vice-versa.

Forgive the mess. I am open to ways to improve this code.

```
class Hints(QGridLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

# Holds the QRadioButtons
        group_box_rounds = QGroupBox()
        h_box_layout_rounds = QHBoxLayout()
        group_box_rounds.setLayout(h_box_layout_rounds)
        self.addWidget(group_box_rounds, 0, 0, 1, 4)

        radio_button_round_1_2 = QRadioButton(string_round_1_2)
        radio_button_round_1_2.click()
        h_box_layout_rounds.addWidget(radio_button_round_1_2)
        radio_button_round_3 = QRadioButton(string_round_3)

# Holds the QWidgets used to display a layout based on what QRadioButton is clicked.
        round_widget = QStackedWidget()
        round_1_2 = Round1And2()
        round_3 = Round3()
        round_widget.addWidget(round_1_2)
        round_widget.addWidget(round_3)
        current_round = round_1_2
        round_widget.setCurrentWidget(round_1_2)
        self.addWidget(round_widget, 1, 0, 2, 1)

        def round_checked(round):
            nonlocal current_round
            round_widget.setCurrentWidget(round)
            current_round = round

        def round_changed(checked):
            if not checked:
                return
            if radio_button_round_1_2.isChecked():
                round_checked(round_1_2)
            if radio_button_round_3.isChecked():
                round_checked(round_3)

        radio_buttons_rounds = []
        radio_buttons_rounds.append(radio_button_round_1_2)
        radio_buttons_rounds.append(radio_button_round_3)
# Here is where I try to set the callback, but the callback never gets called, and yet the corresponding QRadioButtons do switch the layout displayed by QStackedWidget. When these two lines are removed, then the QRadioButtons do nothing, therefore this code somehow connects the QRadioButtons to the QStackedWidget. I do not see how.
        for r in radio_buttons_rounds:
            r.toggled.connect(round_changed)
```

Update:
I found out that the methods have to be part of the widget for the callbacks to work. Not sure why.

```
class Hints(QGridLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        group_box_rounds = QGroupBox()
        h_box_layout_rounds = QHBoxLayout()
        group_box_rounds.setLayout(h_box_layout_rounds)
        self.addWidget(group_box_rounds, 0, 0, 1, 4)

        self.radio_button_round_1_2 = QRadioButton(string_round_1_2)
        self.radio_button_round_1_2.click()
        h_box_layout_rounds.addWidget(self.radio_button_round_1_2)
        self.radio_button_round_3 = QRadioButton(string_round_3)
        h_box_layout_rounds.addWidget(self.radio_button_round_3)

        self.round_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.round_1_2 = Round1And2()
        self.round_3 = Round3()
        self.round_widget.addWidget(self.round_1_2)
        self.round_widget.addWidget(self.round_3)
        self.current_round = self.round_1_2
        self.round_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.round_1_2)
        self.addWidget(self.round_widget, 1, 0, 2, 1)

        radio_buttons_rounds = []
        radio_buttons_rounds.append(self.radio_button_round_1_2)
        radio_buttons_rounds.append(self.radio_button_round_3)
# Now the callbacks are called
        for r in radio_buttons_rounds:
            r.toggled.connect(self.round_changed)

    def round_checked(self, round):
        self.round_widget.setCurrentWidget(round)
        self.current_round = round

    def round_changed(self, checked):
        if not checked:
            return
        if self.radio_button_round_1_2.isChecked():
            self.round_checked(self.round_1_2)
        if self.radio_button_round_3.isChecked():
            self.round_checked(self.round_3)
```

Seems like a bad design decision having to write "self." everywhere (For example, you do not need the append "self." everywhere in Java).

I found out that if I remove "r.toggled.connect(round_changed)" from the above, the QstackedWidget will not change the displayed widget. Even though "round_changed" was not called when "r.toggled.connect(round_changed)" was included, clicking a QRadioButton changed the widget displayed by the QStackedWidget. What I do not understand is how the QRadioButtons got connected to the QStackedWidget like that.

```
class Hints(QGridLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        group_box_rounds = QGroupBox()
        h_box_layout_rounds = QHBoxLayout()
        group_box_rounds.setLayout(h_box_layout_rounds)
        self.addWidget(group_box_rounds, 0, 0, 1, 4)

        self.radio_button_round_1_2 = QRadioButton(string_round_1_2)
        self.radio_button_round_1_2.click()
        h_box_layout_rounds.addWidget(self.radio_button_round_1_2)
        self.radio_button_round_3 = QRadioButton(string_round_3)
        h_box_layout_rounds.addWidget(self.radio_button_round_3)

        self.round_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.round_1_2 = Round1And2()
        self.round_3 = Round3()
        self.round_widget.addWidget(self.round_1_2)
        self.round_widget.addWidget(self.round_3)
        self.current_round = self.round_1_2
        self.round_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.round_1_2)
        self.addWidget(self.round_widget, 1, 0, 2, 1)
# Now the QRadioButtons do nothing.
```

Therefore, my guess is that r.toggled.connect(round_changed) did something even though it did not call the method.

Comment: We can certainly forgive the mess, but consider that "messed code" is the main reason for bugs, unexpected errors and unwanted behavior. Besides that, what do you mean with "I found out that if I remove the callback, it does not work."? Also, what is the "bad design decision" you're referring to? The fact that there are a lot of "self" is part of python and, conceptually, OOP: you can call it in some other way, if you want (like, `this`), but you still need a reference to those objects, and since they're member of `self`, you cannot get rid of it.

Comment: I added clarification to my question

Comment: Included comments in the code about the parts that I do not understand too.

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre]: the second radio is not added to the layout, and we don't know what `Round1And2` and `Round3` are. Also note that, usually, layout subclasses are only used to implement layout features and functions, and the "main" class that contains widgets is normally the container widget (a QWidget subclass). Nothing prevents you to do what you're doing, but, conceptually, child widgets are members of a parent *widget*, not of the layout: the layout only *manages* their geometries, but they are always children of a parent QWidget.